# Parsing date from DD/MM/YYYY with Luxon javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

I have a date in this format "DD/MM/YYYY" and I want to convert it to a `DateTime` object with Luxon library. How can I do it?

I know we can use methods like `.fromISO()`, `.fromHTTP()`, `.fromSQL()`, `.fromJSDate()`, and `.fromFormat()` and none of them accepts the format I have, for example: "31/12/2022"

I was trying with `fromFormat( date, 'D' )` but it's invalid because "D" format is equal to "MM/DD/YYYY".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) :

> Create a DateTime from an input string and format string. Defaults to en-US if no locale has been specified, regardless of the system's locale. For a table of tokens and their interpretations, see [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens).

passing `"d/M/yyyy"` as second argument. Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log(DateTime.fromFormat("31/12/2022", "d/M/yyyy").toISO());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.1.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Please have a look at [Parsing](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing) section of the docs and [Table of tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens) to see the list of available tokens. As docs states:

> Note that many tokens supported by the [formatter](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting) are **not** supported by the parser.

in your case "D" is a *format token* you can use *standalone tokens* to parse your input string.